# How to handle 200 status code with error response rest template?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-rest

I want to handle 200 with error response

`final ResponseEntity<ResponseType> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestEntity, ResponseType.class);`

Here I am directly used response model object in rest template and below is my catch block

```
catch (final RestClientException | HttpMessageConversionException ex) {
                throw new CustomException(message, ex);
            }
```

Here I added `HttpMessageConversionException` because I am getting 200 with error response and while transforming that to my success response type class in rest template it throws because in my success response class constructor has field validation.

below is my response class used in rest template

```
@JsonDeserialize(builder = ResponseType.Builder.class)
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Test")
public class ResponseType {

    private final String details;

    private ResponseType(final Builder builder) {
        this.details = OptionalCheck.checkPresent(builder.details, "details");
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }

    //getter

    public static final class Builder {
        private Optional<String> details = Optional.empty();

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "details")
        public Builder withDetails(final String theDetails) {
            this.details = Optional.ofNullable(theDetails);
            return this;
        }


        public ResponseType build() {
            return new ResponseType(this);
        }
    }
}
```

below is stack trace

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.test.ResponseType$Builder]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.test.ResponseType$Builder`, problem: details must be present.
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 5, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:227)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:994)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:977)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:445)
```

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: details must be present.
    at com.test.OptionalCheck.lambda$checkPresent$0(OptionalCheck.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
```

Is any other way to handle this?

Comment: `restTemplate` will not throw any exception for `200` status code

Comment: yes. but while converting to ResponseType.class, I have field validation in my constructor. For mandatory fields I  am throwing IllegalArguementException. That time I got HttpMessageConversionException.

Comment: can you show the exception with stack trace @Bharathi ? and also can you show this `ResponseType` class ?

Comment: added ResponseType class and stack trace

Comment: Did you think using `Error handling` so you will catch the exceptions what you want?

Comment: try `@jsonignoreproperties(ignoreunknown = true)` on `ResponseType` class @Bharathi

Answer (score 0):

For better help, you should show us an example of a good response and of an error response.

But I'll cover an example of how you should do it.

Let's say a good response looks like this:

```json
{
    "details": {
        ...
    }
}
```

and an error response looks like:

```json
{
    "error": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you must define the response type as a class with 2 fields: `details` and `error`, then check which is present and react as needed, e.g.

```java
DetailsOrErrorResponse response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, DetailsOrErrorResponse.class);
if (response.getError() != null) {
    // handle error here
} else if (response.getDetails() == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid response: Missing `details` or `error`");
} else {
    // handle good response here
}
```

Comment: Unsatisfying as heck! But as the problem is downstream...